#  Bitmap static in android

Tags: android, static, bitmap

My activity have several static bitmap arrays,but sometimes those static bitmap is gone when i open other activity, such as load photo using the intent below:
My Code

```
 Intent intent = newIntent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

When i stay too long in intent which i call to pick image, all my static bitmap array is gone.. i can't use final static because i change those bitmap on run time..
How do i prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading the other bitmaps? What are your suspend and resume functions for your first activity?

Comment: public static Bitmap[] bmpFace;
if(bmpFace == null) bmpFace = new Bitmap[Constant.template_card_face[position]]; 

When i got the result back from onActivityResult i set bmpFace[0]=bitmap;
Sometimes it's working fine, but sometimes if i want to set it, it give me error msg --> 01-09 15:41:51.905: WARN/System.err(1955): java.lang.NullPointerException

onSuspend and onResume i did nothing..
Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this may fall under restoring with onResume. The behavior sounds right - sometimes when returning to the Activity, resources are missing.

Also is the NullPointerException for the bitmap variable or the bmpFace variable?

Comment: NullPointerException is for bmpFace variable.
Sometimes i see message in log that no more background resource..
I'm just afraid that when the user pick the image too long will cause this error, but it rarely happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android offers no guarantees on static references like that. The reason that it sometimes works and sometimes not is basically because sometimes the garbage collector(GC) has set your array to null and sometimes not. The GC will not set your reference to null if you activity is active, but it will if it has to when your activity is inactive, e.g. not visible.

You need to add a check for null in the onResume() method and make a new Bitmap array if necessary. As for the bitmaps themselves that are stored in the array, you need to store them in memory. Check the following article and read about saving cache files via the getCacheDir() method. That is basically what you need since the data does not need to be stored persistently across multiple sessions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html